# Google Cloud SDK importError: no module named cloud.google

Tags: python, cloud, platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to Linux and trying to run a Python script that needs the following: 'from google.cloud import pubsub'

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
```

How can I give access to this module? I have installed Google's Cloud SDK. I assume it has something to do with providing the path to this SDK "module" in some file?

Answer (score 4):

If this only happened when you deployed to app engine, then considering the following solution (it worked for me):

1, in the same directory of your app engine project (usually where you put your **.py, **.yaml, and index.html), add a python file named "appengine_config.py"

2, put the following code into your appengine_config.py:

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

3, make sure on that directory you also has a "lib" folder that contains your library import (check if google.cloud is there)

4, deploy it and that problem should be resolved.

Comment: on pycharm it worked using this in appengine_config.py

Answer (score 2):

If you want use pubsub in Python script, you should install via pip like this:

- Install pip and virtualenv

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
  sudo pip install virtualenv
  ```
- Create new environment and activate that

  ```
  cd project-folder
  virtualenv env
  source env/bin/activate
  ```
- Install pubsub module

  ```
  pip install google-cloud-pubsub
  ```