# Access Google Pub/Sub from App Engine standard environment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using the python standard environment and would like to publish a message to google pub/sub. However, it appears that the google cloud libraries are not included with the environment, at least without some sort of additional configuration.

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
ImportError: No module named cloud
```

This is running on a deployed instance. The example google gives for using pub/sub is in the flexible environment.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462495/google-cloud-sdk-importerror-no-module-named-cloud-google

Comment: I considered that approach. My concern was the size (you have to copy all of your libaries into a subdirectory) and the likelyhood something wouldn't work right since everything must be pure-python and some monkey patching is required to get some libraries working correctly in the standard environment.

Comment: They recommend to use an "older" client library if running on standard environment - [source](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python). I'm not sure which library they are referring to though. In the worst case, I think you'd have to write a bit of custom code to call their REST API?

Answer (score 5):

App Engine Standard's Python2.7 runtime does not support Pub/Sub Cloud Client Library, only Pub/Sub Service API Client Library. There's [some new code samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/pubsub) that shows how to do that.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import base64

service = build('pubsub', 'v1')

topic_path = 'projects/{your_project_id}/topics/{your_topic}'

service.projects().topics().publish(
    topic=topic_path, body={
      "messages": [{
          "data": base64.b64encode(data)
      }]
    }).execute()
```

Comment: important to note that you will need to include the `google-api-python-client` dependency in some sort of `lib` folder before deploying as it is not included by default in Appengine Standard Environment, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring